# Breaking Shabbat for Livelihood

Tags: halacha, shabbat, parnassah-livelihood

1. Can one desecrate/be michalel Shabbat for the sake of his livelihood/parnassah at risk? For instance, if one has a flock of sheep (his entire livelihood) and lives in an area highly prone to thievery, can he make rounds on Shabbat with a flashlight, assuming that is the only option to protect his livestock?
2. Can he turn the flashlight on before Shabbat & keep it on for the whole Shabbat?

3. If he must turn the flashlight on and off to conserve energy is that allowed (in a scenario where he is stuck with no other option)?
4. Can someone besides the owner turn on the flashlight to help out?

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch OC 307:10 and 19 with Mishna Brura.